# Kingston HyperX Cloud 2 USB Headphones not working on startup

Tags: usb, sound, kde, headphones

Every time I boot my computer, I have to unplug and plug back in my usb headphones. I tried setting it as the default audio device in settings but that doesn't work either. Any pointers toward fixing this would be greatly appreciated. The headphones work perfectly if plugged in using the standard 3.5mm jack but unfortunately not through usb.

Alsa information is available at this link as requested: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=9e92513425bf37b3cef6e61338cddd0b9ee0cec0

pulseverbose.log file: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/54d02756eda4c27e7100fbdc5951b1cf

syslog: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3a6f06cb517e0e07d1f38380af4eeb21

Comment: please follow the instructions in https://askubuntu.com/tags/sound/info

Comment: I have edited the initial post with my alsa information as per that link

Comment: Thank you for your edit, but I should have told you that I suspect an issue with Pulseaudio, sorry for that. Could you please post this as well? Your `/var/log/syslog` should also contain hints about not detecting the headphones.

Comment: Edited the post to contain the pulseverbose.log file... unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to post another link in my text so the syslog file can be found at https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3a6f06cb517e0e07d1f38380af4eeb21

Comment: I found the following in PulseAudio log (and the lines after that) which may give a hint at the problem, I could be wrong though: `could not open configuration file /usr/share/alsa/ucm/HyperX 7.1 Audio/HyperX 7.1 Audio.conf` I'm not sure if anyone else around here can help you, I'd suggest asking the friendly guys at the [pulseaudio mailing](https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/pulseaudio-discuss) list for help. Post the log as text (attachments may get filtered) tell them which release of Ubuntu you are using (if possible re-check with the latest) and all other relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I started to have this same issue after enabling Ultra Fast Boot or Fast Boot on my motherboard bios, disabling it solves the issue, may be this could help you.

I have the hyperx cloud II, ubuntu gnome 16.04 and a z170 gigabyte motherboard.